# Probability: discrete, binomial or uniform?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

> There are 11 professors who want to vote one of their own to be a representative. They will each express only one preference. Assume each professor is equally likely not to vote for him/herself, and that otherwise he/she will vote for someone else at random. What is the probability that a person who voted for himself/herself received a total of five votes?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Shuri2060 voting for themselves is equally likely, so $p = .5$.

Comment: I believe it does not also, but i am lost for words as i have tried almost every case. If it helps, the answer is 0.00096... so this is not the solution..thank you

Comment: Ignore my earlier answer - I'd made a silly error. @Mark I don't understand..?

Comment: I reckon the probability is ${10\choose4}((1-p)(\frac{1}{10}))^4(p+(1-p)(\frac{9}{10}))^6$ where $p$ is the chance a professor chooses themself.

Comment: I suspect the answer may be $0.0009648081$

Comment: Can you elaborate?? @Shuri2060

Comment: Thats the answer... care to explain how to reach it?? @Henry

Comment: Plugging $0.5$ into what I've given does indeed give that answer. But I don't understand why $p=0.5$.

Comment: @Shuri2060 $p = .5$ because each professor chooses _equally likely_ whether to vote for themselves or not.  This means that their choice is the _uniform distribution_ on whatever set of possible choices there are.  As there are two choices (vote for themselves, or don't), this means $P[vote for self] = P[vote for other]$, so each must happen with probability $1/2$.

Comment: @Mark I don't see why $p=1$ is not a possibility given the wording? 'each professor is equally likely not to vote for him/herself'

Comment: @Shuri2060 there are two different events that can happen.  Say that event $1$ (professor votes for themselves) happens with probability $p$, and event 2 (professor votes for someone else) happens with probability $q$.  We know that $p + q = 1$ already.  These events happen _equally likely_, which means that $p = q$, so we get that $p + p = 1\implies p = 1/2 = q$.  See something like [this](http://www.learnalberta.ca/content/memg/Division02/Equally%20Likely%20Events/index.html) for more on equally likely events.

Comment: @Mark Perhaps this is down to the ambiguity of wording. I'm interpreting it as: Let professor $i$ have probability $p_i$ of voting for themself. 'each professor is equally likely not to vote for him/herself' $\implies 1-p_1=1-p_2=...=1-p_{11}\implies p_1=p_2=...=p_{11}$. Hence let $p=p_i$

Comment: @Shuri2060 I agree that the wording is lacking somewhat.  I've interpreted it as two "checks" - first "Do I vote for myself or not" (equally likely, so $p = 1/2$), and then "Of everyone else, who do I vote for?" (not mentioned being equally likely, but as it's only specified as "random" that's what I'm assuming).

Comment: @J.Moriarty Is the wording you've given the one originally provided in the question? Otherwise I'd suggest something like 'each professor is equally likely to vote for themself as not themself. If they do not vote for themself, then they randomly vote for someone else'

Comment: @Shuri2060 That is the wording provided, but i agree it is somewhat inadequate

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i\sim\text{Bern}(1/2)$ be the probability someone votes for themselves, and then $Y_i\mid X_i = 0\sim\text{Unif}\{1,\dots,10\}$ be the probability they vote for someone else at random given that they're not voting for themselves.
In this language, we have that $Y_i$ is the random variable encoding who professor $i$ votes for.
It's not too hard to see that $\mathbb{P}[Y_i = i] = 1/2$, and $\mathbb{P}[Y_i = j] = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{10}$ for $i\neq j$.

The probability you're interested in is the same as "What's the probability that 4 other people vote for this person".
There are $10$ total (other) people.
We can think of this as a Binomial r.v. with $p = 1/20$, as that's the probability someone else votes for our person.
So, we have that $Z\sim\text{Binom}(10, 1/20)$, and:
$$\mathbb{P}[Z = 4] = \binom{10}{4}(1/20)^4(19/20)^6 = 0.0009648081064453125
$$

Comment: Much appreciated, but can you explain as to why the probability of a person voting for another is 1/2 x 1/10 ?

Comment: @J.Moriarty the easiest way to figure this out might be with a probability tree.  First, with $p = 1/2$ a voter chooses to vote for themself or not.  If they choose to vote for themself you're done.  Otherwise, they choose (from 10 people) to vote for 1 at random.  Assuming a uniform distribution, we have that the chance they vote for some else specifically is $1/10$.  So, to get to the specific leaf on the tree we're interested in, first something with probability $1/2$ happens, then something with probability $1/10$ happens, so the total probability is them multiplied together, or $1/20$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The probability is

$${n\choose k}\left(\left(1-p\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^k\left(1-(1-p)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{n-k}$$

where $n$ is the number of professors there are excluding the one we are interested in, $p$ is the chance that a professor votes for themself and $k$ is the number of votes the professor we're interested in gets (except from themself).

As you can probably see, this is actually $P(X=k)$ where $X\sim B(n,(1-p)(\frac{1}{n}))$

This gives

$${10\choose4}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\right)^4\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\right)^6\approx0.000965$$

---

Explanation:

We know that the professor concerned votes for themself, leaving $k$ votes from other professors.

From the other professors, we need to select $k$ which vote for the professor concerned, and $n-k$ that don't.

This means that the probability we're interested in is

$${n\choose k}P(\text{$k$ professors vote for our professor})P(\text{$n-k$ professors don't vote for our professor})$$

We are given that all professors have an equally likely chance of voting for themselves and that chance is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the situation of each professor is identical and we get

$${n\choose k}P(\text{a professor votes for our professor})^kP(\text{a professor doesn't vote for our professor})^{n-k}$$

Now,

$$P(\text{a professor votes for our professor})=P(\text{a professor doesn't vote for themself})P(\text{a professor chooses our professor}\,|\,\text{a professor doesn't vote for themself})=(1-p)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$P(\text{a professor doesn't vote for our professor})=1-(1-p)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Much appreciated!!